# RewriteMap not working as expected

Tags: linux, bash, apache-httpd

I am trying to block access to certain url :

https://example.com/questions/topic

I have a blacklist.txt file that contains the following :

```
questions/topic deny
```

and then I have the following in the configuration :

```
 RewriteMap access txt:path_to_blacklist.txt
 RewriteCond ${access:%{REQUEST_URI}} deny [NC]
 RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

but I found that I still can open https://example.com/questions/topic normally but when I tried to use the below configuration instead of RewriteMap :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} questions/topic  [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

it worked successfully and I wasnt able to access the url. so how can I achieve the same result with RewriteMap ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a "bite yourself in the behind" oversight: `${REQUEST_URI}` includes the leasing slash. If you have

```
/questions/topic deny
```

in your file, you should be fine. (RewriteMap does *exact matches* for key lookup; when you put your `questions/topic` in the RewriteCond explicitly, it's a regexp match, and since it's not anchored with `^` and/or `$`, that boils down to a substring match in your case.)

As a matter of personal taste: since your `RewriteRule` does not do anything with the match, you can write `RewriteRule ^` instead of `RewriteRule .*` for "match anything". There is a chance that the former is faster, since it doesn't need to look at the string, where `.*` is greedy and will read all of it.